# How to access recordType in Test Methods with seeAllData = false

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am writting a test method for a certain code.This code is fetching Record Type detail from an Object `Service_Form__c`.

**Class:**

```
String recordTypeName;
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult srfDescribe = Service_Form__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
   for (Schema.RecordTypeInfo recordType : srfDescribe.getRecordTypeInfos()) {
      if (recordType.isDefaultRecordTypeMapping()) {
         recordTypeName = recordType.Name;
      }
   }
```

With in the test class with `seeAllData= true`, without any effort, I am able to fetch all recordType deatil from the Object. However, if I am considering `seeAlldata = false`, then `srfDescribe` is coming null.

Is there any other way, so that we can access a Object's recordtype in the testMethods without inserting an Object record and assigning recordtypes to that record ?

Comment: I copied your code and placed it into an empty test, I was able to do a system.debug on the record type name and it prints out my default record type. Try just testing the above and add a debug to see what you get, or add your test class to your question to see if there is something else causing the null value.

Answer (score 9):

Recordtype can be directly queried and you do not have to use SeeAllData for getting record type info

Reference:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm

> However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata
>   objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:
>
> User
>
> Profile
>
> Organization
>
> AsyncApexJob
>
> CronTrigger
>
> **RecordType**
>
> ApexClass
>
> ApexTrigger
>
> ApexComponent
>
> ApexPage

Eg:

`RecordType rt = [select id,Name from RecordType where SobjectType='Account' and Name='A' Limit 1];`

If you want to do it without using a query:

Reference : http://salesforceapexcodecorner.blogspot.com/2012/03/record-type-for-crating-test-class-data.html

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult cfrSchema = Schema.SObjectType.Account; 
Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> AccountRecordTypeInfo = cfrSchema.getRecordTypeInfosByName(); 
Id rtId = AccountRecordTypeInfo .get('A').getRecordTypeId();

Account Acc = new Account(Name='test',recordtypeid=AccountRecordTypeInfo .get('A').getRecordTypeId());
insert Acc;
```

Comment: note that the doc above is incomplete, it should also include `StaticResource` which is most definitely available without `SeeAllData=true`. I have filed a doc feedback on this.