# Record Type Name in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, record-type

I have a test class that creates records for use in unit tests.  One of the components creates an Opportunity record, but I don't know how to add a Record Type to the Opp.  I know I can use RecordTypeID, but since I don't want to hardcode that, I am looking to use the Record Type name.  Can anyone help me figure out the syntax I need to use?  Thanks,

```
public static Opportunity createOppNew (Id acctId){ 
    Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity();
      opp1.Name = 'Test Renewal Opp';
      opp1.StageName = 'Phase 1';
      opp1.CloseDate = Date.today().addYears(1);
      opp1.Renewal__c = 'Yes';
      opp1.Effective_Date__c = Date.today().addYears(1);
      opp1.RP_Contract_Start__c = Date.today().addDays(1);
      opp1.Term__c = 12;
      opp1.AccountId = acctId;
      opp1.RP_Customer_Engagement__c = 0;
    return opp1;
}
```

Comment: Do you have SeeAllData = true on your test?

Comment: Guys, you don't need SeeAllData=true to query record types:  https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_testing_seealldata_using.htm|SkinName=webhelp   You really want to avoid turning that on, and avoid unpredicted results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer to [How to access recordType in Test Methods with seeAllData = false](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46691/how-to-access-recordtype-in-test-methods-with-seealldata-false) which should provide you with the means to add the RecordType without needing to hard code the ID into your test class. In essence, you can either use a schema call to obtain it or else put it in a static resource.

Answer (score 0):

public static schema.describesobjectresult caseRecordType=Case.sobjecttype.getdescribe();
    public static map caseRecordTypeMap=caseRecordType.getrecordtypeinfosbyname();

```
public static id RecordTypeId= caseRecordTypeMap.get('your Record Type Name here').getrecordtypeid();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. See here: [What would be the best approach to get the recordtype id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11968/what-would-be-the-best-approach-to-get-the-recordtype-id)

for a list of possible solutions. In short, the fastest and simplest way is to query the RecordType object and put 'where DeveloperName = X' in the Where.